# UISearchController and navigations

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

Navigating from `searchResultsViewController` of `UISearchController` to a `UIViewController` that does not require a `UINavigationBar`. The `UINavigationBar` never hides and is always present when the animation of pushing is happening.

The `UINavigationController` used to push is the `UINavigationController` of the `UIViewController` of which the `UISearchBar` is a subview of.

The goal was to have the push animation while no `UINavigationBar` visible in the pushed `UIViewController`. This achieved without an issue when pushing on a `UINavigationController` not linked to an active `UISearchController`. The `UINavigationBar` is hidden in the `viewWillAppear:` of the pushed view-controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand correctly but try end search if its active with `[self.searchController setActive:NO];` then only do the push, so the Navigation Controller will be restore before u push

Comment: Its UISearchController not UISearchDisplayController.

Comment: Oh right, then use `[self.searchController setActive:NO];` or `self.searchController.active = NO;` :D